# Take some action when errors occur with nginx

Tags: nginx, debian, monitoring

I have a nginx/1.2.1 on Debian 7.0 x64 and i want to take some action when some error occurs, something like send mail to me.
I found on the web ways to monitor files and take some action when they are changed, but if i monitor the error.log i will have to read the content of it and remove the content always after send a email, i have to do this to send only last error (errors) but i want to keep the error.log intact.

What better way to do this error monitoring?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use something like [Logstash](http://logstash.net/) to monitor your files. Logstash (and most other well-written) log analysis tools will keep track of their current log location and hence, will not take duplicate actions.

Logstash can use a variety of mechanisms for sending alerts: email, XMPP, twitter, etc.

Also, it is worth noting that logstash is not meant to be run in "batch mode" or to be run periodically from cron. You start up logstash and it is constantly watching your log files and will send alerts immediately when it finds lines that match your specified pattern.